# Is there a way to force Visual Studio to render ItemStyle’s HorizontalAlign as a CSS rule and not html attribute?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

1) If I set `HorizontalAlign` property inside `GridView’s ItemStyle` tag:

```
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```

then Visual Studion  will render this property as `<td align=”center”>`

a) Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to instead render `HorizonatalAlign` property  as a style rule :

```
<td style=”text-align:center;” ... >
```

thanx

Comment: Interesting question, I'm going to assume probably not though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a CssClass for your ItemStyle and use CSS to style the line.